# How to do redirection with traefik for custom docker ports

Tags: docker, redirect, port, traefik

Hello  I have a problem with redirecting HTTP requests to HTTP, when traefik is running in docker and I have mapped the ports.

I am running traefik (v1.5.4 on CentOS as a docker service.
The docker-compose.yml I use to start (docker stack deploy) looks like this

```
# use docker stack deploy to start a service running  traefik
version: '3.6'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api  --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - "70:80"
      - "7443:443"
      - "7070:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/frank/docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
```

The reason for mapping the ports in docker is that on my development system I want to run traefik in parallel to an existing apache.

In my traefik.toml file I try to redirect from Port 80 to 443.

```
 [entryPoints]

    # Port 80 (HTTP) is redirected to PORT 443 (HTTPS)
    [entryPoints.http]
       address = ":80"
       [entryPoints.http.redirect]
          entryPoint = "https"

    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
```

Before adding the certificates für HTTPS, I wanted to test the redirection.
It did not work.

I send a request to **http:/server.net:70/xxx**. And I got a redirection to **http:/server.net:443/xxx**. What I need or expected was that I would be redirected to  **http:/server.net:7443/xxx**.
Thus my request is not redirected to my app

Is there a way to make this happen?
I think I could in the toml file redirect to port 7443. However, I do not like this solution, since then I will in the traefik configuration use information from the docker configuration. I would prefer to keep them as independent as possible?